# Messaging/Chat System - Directing messages to more than one recipient

Tags: php

I have built a messaging/chat system and I needed to extend it's functionality. When a user posts a message, they have the option to direct the message to one or more users. Here is the structure of the two tables I made.

```
chat_message    CREATE TABLE `chat_message` (
 `chat_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `chat_message` text NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'time message was sent',
 PRIMARY KEY (`chat_message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

chat_to_users   CREATE TABLE `chat_to_users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `to_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `from_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `read_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'time user read message',
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm trying to output the messages now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQAvy.jpg

That is really 3 messages but it's showing 5 in total because 2 of the 3 were directed to more than one user.

I want it to show something more like "From: from_user - To: to_user1, to_user2, etc." Just adding the additional usernames if the message was directed to more than one person.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
function fetch_order_messaging_history( $order_id, $pdo ) {

    //construct SQL query
    $query = "
             SELECT 
             msg.chat_message_id,
             msg.order_id,
             msg.chat_message,
             msg.timestamp AS sent_timestamp,
             usr.id AS chat_to_users_id,
             usr.message_id,
             usr.to_user_id,
             usr.from_user_id,
             usr.read_timestamp AS read_timestamp,
             usr.status
             FROM chat_message AS msg 
             LEFT JOIN chat_to_users AS usr 
             ON msg.chat_message_id = usr.message_id 
             WHERE msg.order_id = $order_id 
             ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC
             ";

    //prep, execute, & fetch SQL results
    $statement = $pdo->prepare ( $query );
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    //construct HTML for browser output
    $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        $user_name = '';

        $track_msg_id = $row['chat_message_id'];

        if ( $row[ 'from_user_id' ] == $_SESSION['user_id' ] ) {
            $from_user_name = '<b class="text-success">You</b>';
        } else {
            $from_user_name = '<b class="text-success">' . get_user_name( $row[ 'from_user_id' ], $pdo ) . '</b>';
        }

        $output .=  '
                    <li style="border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc">
                        <p>' . 'From: ' . $from_user_name . ' To: ' . get_user_name( $row[ 'to_user_id' ], $pdo ) . ' - '. $row[ 'chat_message' ] . '
                            <div align="right">
                            - <small><em>' . $row[ 'sent_timestamp' ] . '</em></small>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    ';

    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    //output HTML to browser
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregation formula and a `GROUP BY` to accomplish this:

```
         SELECT 
         msg.chat_message_id,
         msg.order_id,
         msg.chat_message,
         msg.timestamp AS sent_timestamp,
         usr.id AS chat_to_users_id,
         usr.message_id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(usr.to_user_id SEPARATOR ',') AS to_user_ids,
         usr.from_user_id,
         usr.read_timestamp AS read_timestamp,
         usr.status
         FROM chat_message AS msg 
         LEFT JOIN chat_to_users AS usr 
         ON msg.chat_message_id = usr.message_id 
         WHERE msg.order_id = $order_id 
         GROUP BY
           msg.chat_message_id,
           msg.order_id,
           msg.chat_message,
           msg.timestamp,
           usr.id,
           usr.message_id,
           usr.from_user_id,
           usr.read_timestamp,
           usr.status
         ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC
```

You may have to figure out how to aggregate (group up, sum, choose the "max", etc) your `read_timestamp` or `status` if those are different for each record as well.

Comment: I thought there was a way to do that with GROUP BY and couldn't figure it out. I tried your suggestion and get this PDO error: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPERATOR ',') AS to_user_ids, usr.from_user_id, usr.read_timestamp AS' at line 8`

Comment: That error is because I don't know how to spell SEPARATOR. I will update the question with the correct spelling. I'm 41 and have been spelling that word for years on the regular and I still can't get it right.

Comment: It's not returning them as a CSV..just one number for each row.

Comment: I suspect then that your `usr.read_timestamp` is different for each record as well (and possibly your `status`. If you get different `read_timestamp` for the 1 message to multiple people, how would you like those to be displayed? Perhaps consider just dropping that completely from the query (both SELECT and GROUP BY) since it's sort of nonsensical at the message granularity anyways. Essentially every column needs to either be aggregated with an aggregate formula like `GROUP_CONCAT` or `MAX()` or `SUM()` OR it needs to be in your `GROUP BY` in which case distinct values will cause separate row.

Comment: Okay I figured out what you mean. I just removed all of the other items from group by except msg.chat_message_id and now it's working.

Comment: What if I did want to get the read timestamps in it? I'd like to display when a user reads the message.

Comment: I guess it just depends on how you want to display it. You are getting a single row per message, but you have multiple users with multiple read timestamps, so you have to think through that. You could do `GROUP_CONCAT(usr.read_timestamp ORDER BY usr.to_user_id SEPARATOR ',') as timestamps` and also add that `ORDER BY usr.to_user_id` in your other `GROUP_CONCAT` to insure the ordering is the same then parse it in PHP afterwards.